# Problems of General Relativity on small and large scales

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity, cosmological-constant

As far as I know, the most important problem of GR on large scales is the cosmological constant problem which in some manner can be thought of as a dark energy problem (please correct me if I am wrong). I have made some reading on that and I believe I understood what's going on a little bit. However, I am stuck on the small scale problems of GR. I know that quantum effects become important on small scales and since there is no quantum description of GR, the theory fails on these regions. I have heard that one of the reasons for doing massive gravity is to solve this problem and this is also somehow related to the dark matter phenomena. But I don't exactly understand which problem(s) of GR can be solved by doing massive gravity. **Can someone explain in a simple way what are the problems of GR in the context of the reasons that pushed people to study massive gravity and how do we expect to solve these problems (what are the clues?) by studying that topic?**

Comment: There aren't any problems of GR, sahin. The problem is with "endowing the graviton with a nonzero mass" when the graviton remains hypothetical.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12093/2451

Comment: Here is a list of problems in GR that have yet to be solved, or in some cases even adequately formulated: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/50521/.  The list is from a mathematician, so it's from a mathematical viewpoint, but he states everything in intuitively understandable language (just barely).